# Knex migrate latest programmatically

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, synchronization, es6-promise, knex.js

I am trying to following stuff while starting a node app. I need to export my db object to other modules, so I need to export db.

The problem is migration code may give error, but because of asynchronous nature of nodejs, db config had already been exported. I am looking to synchronize following code, so that export happens only if migration completes.

The other way around this may be abstract out db initialization from migration part, but I want the application to shut down, if the migration fails.

```
/*
  1. Db init
  2. Migration stuff
*/
const db = knex(config);
(async () => {
try {
    const migrate = async () => db.migrate.latest();
    await migrate();
} catch(ex) {
    console.log('Error migrating: ', ex);
}
})();

module.exports = db;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to delay the export of a module.

If you want to exit on error, you can simple add `process.exit()` in the `catch` block.

However, I would suggest you add an initialization "guard" in your main file. What I do is put all the initialization code that needs to be done before the application starts in a function that returns a `Promise` (or takes a callback), import this function in my main file, and only import the rest of the application once it succeeds.

Example:

init.js:

```
var db;

function initialize(callback) {
    try {
        db = initializeDatabase();
        callback(null);
    } catch (ex) {
        callback(ex);
    }
}

exports.initialize = initialize;
exports.db = db;
```

main.js:

```
const init = require('./init.js');

init.initialize(function (error) {
    if (error) console.log("Initialization failed with error: " + error.toString());
    else {
        const file1 = require('./file1.js');
        const file2 = require('./file2.js');
        // Import the rest of the application...
    }
});
```

Now when you import `db` in `file1.js` and `file2.js` you can be sure that the initialization and migration did succeed.